# Delete query in treasure-data/hadoop?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I try to write a query to delete some rows in treasure-data but the server ignored it. I'm missing documentation to resolve this issue.

Here is the logs:

```
    Use 'td job:show 2485728' to show the status.
queued...
  started at 2013-04-18T10:22:32Z
  Hive history file=/mnt/hive/tmp/2073/hive_job_log__336863980.txt
  finished at 2013-04-18T10:22:39Z
  Ignored "delete from mytable where time < unix_timestamp() - 30*60*60*24"
```

Comment: Try the presto engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no delete statement in HIVE. One possible trick could be rewriting the table:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE time >= unix_timestamp() - 30*60*60*24
```